# Eclipse based report designer for JasperReports

Tags: jasper-reports

Some time ago, I used IReport to create reports. 
Now I am an Eclipse developer and need something integrated into Eclipse. 
I found JasperAssistant, JasperWave and JasperStudio and would like to hear somebody who has experience with these tools ?

Answer (score 2):

JasperAssistant is a stagnant project, it hasn't been updated in years, so unless you're tied to using an older version of JasperReports I really wouldn't consider it.

JasperWave is good. It's easy to use and more reliable than the older versions of iReport, though it has it's issues. I'm using this personally and would recommend it, but I confess I have iReport as a backup and launch that instead if know I won't be touching code. Also, JasperWave is only made for JR 3.7.6, so if you want to use the latest version of JR you'll want to give it a miss.

JasperStudio is the latest thing from Jaspersoft, and seeing that it is from them I have high expectations. I'd definitely try it out, but as far as I know it's only for JR 4.1.1 (I'm fixed to using 3.7.6). There's probably a much greater chance of this being constantly updated as newer versions of JR are released, so this is what I'd choose if I were starting from scratch now.

Answer (score 0):

Jasper Wave does not have the basic functionality of Tables and Crosstabs so that is also not of much use.

Jasper Studio is the way to go.